# How, or can, I get python -mjson.tool to maintain the order of the attributes

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I know little of python other than this simple invocation:  `python -m json.tool {someSourceOfJSON}`

Note how the source document is ordered "id", "z", "a" but the resulting JSON document presents the attributes "a", "id", "z".

```
$ echo '{ "id": "hello", "z": "obj", "a": 1 }' | python -m json.tool
{
    "a": 1,
    "id": "hello",
    "z": "obj"
}
```

How, or can, I make the `json.tool` thing maintain the order of the attributes from the original JSON document?

The python version is whatever comes with this MacBookPro

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.15
```

Comment: `sort_keys=False` to `json.tool`, not sure how you pass that to a module tho. It's odd, because they've added [--sort-keys](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/58a871227e5b) flag which is intended to actually [sort the keys](https://bugs.python.org/issue21650). Are you running a old version of python by any chance? Because I [can't reproduce](https://i.imgur.com/TWG2nUW.png).

Comment: problem is if json tool returns a dictionary, the order is clobbered. What is your goal?

Comment: Python dictionaries only maintain the input order of the keys since 3.7. Earlier versions don't.

Comment: @BoarGules That explains it, running 3.7.2 as the default over here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's possible with `python -m json.tool` but is with a one liner (which I'm guessing is the actual X/Y root problem) :

```
echo '{ "id": "hello", "z": "obj", "a": 1 }' | python -c "import json, sys, collections; print(json.dumps(json.loads(sys.stdin.read(), object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict), indent=4))"
```

Result:

```
{
    "id": "hello",
    "z": "obj",
    "a": 1
}
```

This is essentially the following code, but without the immediate objects and some readability compromises, such as oneline imports.

```
import json
import sys
import collections

# Read from stdin / pipe as a str
text = sys.stdin.read()

# Deserialise text to a Python object.
# It's most likely to be a dict, depending on the input
# Use `OrderedDict` type to maintain order of dicts.
my_obj = json.loads(text, object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)

# Serialise the object back to text
text_indented = json.dumps(my_obj, indent=4)

# Write it out again
print(text_indented)
```

Comment: Nice.  That is one alias away from me never again understanding how this works ;).  I really should learn some Python.

Comment: @BobKuhar I've updated the answer to include an explanation of why this works. I hope it helps with your introduction to Python 

Comment: this is great. In my case I wanted to sort them and json.tool was making them random. I used your method with a `sort_keys=True`